# Remove inside image border with css

Tags: image, css

I want to remove this border inside image with css anyone can help me to solve this.

the image border is object.

example given below:

[image]

Thanks..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I recommend using an image editor to remove the borders, there is a CSS hack for this:

**Negative margins:**

1. Wrap the image inside a container and set `overflow: hidden` after
   defining the dimensions(width and height). Make sure the dimensions are slightly less than the image dimensions.
2. Set negative margins for the image inside. The margin value is relative to the size of the border.

```css
.borderless-img {
  width: 118px;
  height: 58px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.borderless-img img {
  margin: -1px 0 0 -1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="borderless-img">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcnpS.jpg" />
</div>
```

**Scaling image:**

This method will increase the size of the image, might distort it to a very little extent. It works well for your solution since it would remove the small border.

*Cons: Not recommended to hide big part of images.*

```css
.borderless-img {
  width: 118px;
  height: 58px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.borderless-img img {
  transform: scale(1.055);
}
```

```html
<div class="borderless-img">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcnpS.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: is it responsive friendly?

Comment: What is the reason for not using an image editor? :) Responsive friendly, no because you are setting a fixed width and height for the container.

Comment: not an issue...thanks @manoj

Answer (score 3):

you can use `clip-path` on [modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path) so you wouldn't need to add a wrapper and set the size of the image

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Gpoamy

```
img {
    -webkit-clip-path: inset(1px 1px 1px 1px);
    clip-path: inset(1px 1px 1px 1px)
}
```

On older browsers (and `IE`) you could just use `clip` (although this requires to specify the size of the rectangle and an `absolute` position)

---

Otherwise another approach, with a wider support across browsers, might uses an `outline` (with the same colour of the background) and a negative `outline-offset` — actually you're overlapping the black border with another one. (tested both on Chrome and Firefox).

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPZvKe

```
img {
    outline: 1px #fff solid; 
    outline-offset: -1px;
}
```

Of course these examples work when the border width included inside the image is exactly `1px`. If your image has a thicker border then change all the values according to the thickness

Comment: I could have suggested this solution, but currently this is not even supported in Firefox 40.0.3, works on latest Chrome though.

Comment: Upvoted for outline method. :)